# Result = result + [i]?

Tags: java, loops

```
 class Example {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
      double nums[] = {10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4, 14.5};
      double result = 0;
      int i;

      for(i=0; i<5; i++)
       result = result + nums[i];

      System.out.println("Average is " + result / 5);
     }
    }
```

Sorry if the question is too stupid to ask, but I need to know. why do we have to declare double result = 0? 
and why write result = result + nums[i]? why cant we write just result = nums [i]?

Comment: 1. `result = 0` - initialises the result because it is good programming practice.
2. `result = result + nums[i]` keeps adding to result the value of the previous assigned value of `result` plus the current (`nums[i]`) value in the array.

Comment: If you were adding up the `nums` on paper, you'd start with zero then for each value cross out the old total, add on the new `nums[i]`, then write the new value down. That's basically how to picture the answers to your questions.

Comment: its simple, we store the result of sum of all elements seen until now. for first element we have seen only one element hence result is 0 at the start and we add any number we see to it until we see the last element.

Comment: `result += nums[i]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do we have to declare double result = 0?

> It's because your **result** variable is a block variable which means
>   you need to initialize it first before you can use it.

why write result = result + nums[i]? why cant we write just result = nums [i]?

> **result = nums[i]** only assigns the value in the variable.
>   **result = result + nums[i]** assigns the sum value of **result** and **nums[i]**.

You can also use this.

```
result += nums[i];
```

instead of this.

```
result = result + nums[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing `result = nums [i]` will assign the value of `nums[i]` to `result`, while writing `result = result + nums[i]` will assign the current value of `result` plus `nums[i]` to `result`.

So every time you go around your loop, you're *adding* the value of `nums[i]` to `result`, instead of replacing it.

Declaring `result = 0` just initialises `result` to the value of 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) another question, what if I don't write double result = 0?

Comment: _result = 0_ just initialises _result_ to the value of 0. If you don't do this, the compiler will complain when you try to add _nums[i]_ to it, since it's trying to add _nums[i]_ to an unknown value. Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (under the chart in "Default Values") for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! Alright! Alright!, Here it is. A simple explanation -

Suppose You write **result = num[i]** inside the **for-loop**.

During the iteration inside for-loop, where you are writing  **System.out.println("Average is " + result / 5);**

The consequent output will be -

```
For Iteration 1 - Average is 10.1/5
For Iteration 2 - Average is 11.1/5
For Iteration 3 - Average is 12.3/5 
and So on.. for next two iterations.
```

As you can see, they are not adding up. Its just dividing the index value of your array and printing it. 
So, to add the index values of your Array, You need **result = result + nums[i]**

Now, here is a twist. Since, you are writing **result = result + nums[i]**, thus updating the result value. For first Iteration, there will no previous result value. **No updation since previous Value is not known**. Hence, you got yourself **compilation error.**